# Initialization check for std::optional

Tags: c++, option-type

I've been wondering on the consequences of comparing the value of an `optional` value, one which that we're guaranteed for intialization.

Take this example:

```
std::optional<int> test;
test = 2;
if (test > 1)
  std::cout<<test.value();
```

I've run and executed this case locally and it prints `2`. My question is, how is this expression evaluated? I understand from the source code of the `<optional>` header that `operator()` is overloaded to return a `bool` indicating whether the `optional` object was initialized or not. But that still doesn't explain how we entered the code in the `if` block, since I never checked for something like `test.value > 1`.

Here's a link to the overloaded `operator()` I mentioned:

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/optional#L937

Comment: line 1064 in the file you link, but rather than looking at the implementation I'd advise to consult some reference first.

Answer (score 3):

`std::optional` has an [`operator>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_cmp) implemented, which compares two `optional` objects to each other:

```cpp
template< class T, class U >
constexpr bool operator>( const optional<T>& lhs, const optional<U>& rhs );
```

`std::optional` is implicitly constructable from a value.  And since the inputs to this `operator>` take const references, the compiler is able to construct a *temporary* `std::optional<int>` object from the integer literal `1` and compare it to your `test` variable.

Comment: *And std::optional<T> is implicitly constructible from a T value* It is actually conditionally explicit.  This technique wont work with a type that has an explicit constructor.

Comment: So bar my nascent understanding of modern C++, if type T has an explicit constructor, such pieces of code would fail during compilation right?

Comment: @AzizThanawala yes, in which case you would need to use `if (test > optional<T>(value))` instead, where `T` is the desired type and `value` is the desired value of `T`.